# SonarQube Database Upgrade fails

Tags: sonarqube

When upgrading from SonarQube 5.3 to SonarQube 5.64, I get a message

```
Database connection cannot be established. Please check database status and JDBC settings.
```

This message isn't right, since it has executed a certain number of operations before failing.

The last sql-related log record I get shows a message like

```
2016.12.16 14:44:40 TRACE web[sql] time=0ms | sql=INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES ('1154')
```

In the traces (at the TRACE level) I can find no further information about what's going wrong.

Can somebody help us?

Comment: And what kind of logging/trouble indicators are visible on the DB side?

Comment: Nothing we can see. I've tried restarting the SonarQube service without a database rollback: the webapplication starts, but now I have a problem with the LDAP plugin (not authenticating the domain users)

Comment: 2016.12.16 15:19:51 ERROR web[rails] Error from external users provider: exception Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException:

Comment: that's a different question @nilleb

Comment: Concerning the database migration, we have rolled back the database and repeated the operation. It just went fine. I am unable to say what went wrong in the first one.

Comment: Concerning the LDAP plugin related question, I have opened another question.